# MouseEvent handler. delayed in stationary

Tags: java, javafx

I need to know - how much time the mouse was delayed over the component in stationary. I mean how long did it stay completely stationary over a node. I did not find the standard method. Thank you.

Comment: You mean how long the mouse stayed over a node? Or how long did it stay completely stationary over a node?  

At what point do you need this information? When the mouse is clicked?

Comment: I mean  how long did it stay completely stationary over a node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use the `onMouseMoved` handler to do this; You just need to save the time and calculate the difference:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    StackPane root = new StackPane();

    root.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        long lastTriggered = System.currentTimeMillis();

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("last moved " + (t - lastTriggered) + "ms ago");
            lastTriggered = t;
        }
    });

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

You may want to listen for the stage containing the node beinc closed/iconified in addition to that...